# IOS Removing the autocorrect bar completely

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way of removing the autocorrect bar completely?

[image]

I have set:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

but it doesn't remove the bar, just the autocorrection.

Comment: @matt So that means no. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this bar if you set `autocorrectionType` and remove the `inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups` and `inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups`

```
self.textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
    self.textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
    self.textField.autocorrectionType =  .no
```

From [UITextInputAssistantItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputassistantitem) documentation

"

> To hide shortcuts altogether, set the leadingBarButtonGroups and
>   trailingBarButtonGroups properties to nil. Doing so hides only the
>   shortcuts and does not hide the typing suggestions. To hide typing
>   suggestions, you must also set the autocorrectionType property of the
>   responder that displays the keyboard to UITextAutocorrectionType.no.

"